# How to compare two List with JUnit

Tags: spring, junit, java-8

I am trying to compare two Arrays of strings with Java 8 syntax.

```
List<String> days= dayPartsList.get(0).getWeekdays()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(WeekdayModel::getName))
                .map(x -> x.getName().toUpperCase())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<DayOfWeek> daysofWeeks =Arrays
                .stream(DayOfWeek.values())
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.CANADA)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

assertEquals(days,daysofWeeks);
```

When I run the code I get the following error in the console.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.ArrayList<[FRIDAY, MONDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, THURSDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[FRIDAY, MONDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, THURSDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY]>
Expected :java.util.ArrayList<[FRIDAY, MONDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, THURSDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY]> 
Actual   :java.util.ArrayList<[FRIDAY, MONDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, THURSDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY]>
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.monkey.service.intergrationTest.MenuCallTest.readGetDayPartsTest(MenuCallTest.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70
```

The both actual and expected results look like same but the test is still failing. Is anybody has clue what's going here? Thanks

Comment: you have hit the classic saying when you are comparing oranges and apples :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your problem is really not specific to java 8 `Stream`s as 
here you want to compare the `List`s collected by the `Stream`s and not the `Stream`s themselves.

> The both actual and expected results look like same but the test is
>   still failing.

Indeed they look like to have the same "content" but in fact they don't as in your test code you don't assert that two `String`s are equal but you assert that a `List<String>` is equal to a `List<DayOfWeek>`.
The user friendly message associated to the test failure is just a textual representation of the compared objects.

`Assert.assertEquals(Object, Object)` invokes the `equals()` method on the first argument to determinate whether the two objects are equal :

```
public class Assert {
    ...    
    private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
        return expected.equals(actual);
    }
    ...    
}
```

And a `DayOfWeek` object whatever its `toString()` value is very probably not equal in terms of `equals()` method to a `String` object that has the same `String` content.

So, you have to use the same type of element in the `List`s in the expected and the actual to make `assertEqual()` successful.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that I have done a silly mistake.